# sed command doesn't replace the pattern that I want?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed

I have an `index.html` file that has lines like

```
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<link href="css/colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

IOW, it references a lot of `*.js` and `*.css` files. I want to replace all occurrences of `*.js` and `*.css` with `*.css?rel=1569974280190463223` and `*.js?rel=1569974280190463223` where `1569974280190463223` is a timestamp value, so the above lines will look like

```
<script src="js/config.js?rel=1569974280190463223"></script>
<link href="css/colorpicker.min.css?rel=1569974280190463223" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have a shell script that does this

```
timestamp="$(($(date +%s%N)-T))"
sed -i -e 's|\.css"|\.css?rel=$timestamp"|g' -e 's|\.js"|\.js?rel=$timestamp"|g' index.html
```

but `index.html` file ends up looking like

```
<script src="js/config.js?rel=$timestamp"></script>
<link href="css/colorpicker.min.css?rel=$timestamp" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What am I missing in my `sed` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quoting the shell variable `$timestamp` within single quotes.
Please try instead:

```
sed -i -e 's|\.css"|\.css?rel='"$timestamp"'"|g' -e 's|\.js"|\.js?rel='"$timestamp"'"|g' index.html
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this, and it scrolled the file on the screen with the `?rel=xxxx` part that i wanted, but when i looked at the file, it remained unchanged?

Comment: Oops, the `-i` option was missing im my answer. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes I should've caught that. It works now, thanks @thiono!